# What's the next item in the list after a pitchfork?

Tags: candy-box-2

I don't have this one. What is it suppose to be and where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

You get that item by completing the game.

Answer (score 0):

The item in the slot to the right of the pitchfork can be found only after beating the castle and finding all 4 "magic stones".

It is a:

> [Talking candy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/137341/58106)