# Full List of inventory items

Tags: candy-box-2

After beating the game, I still have several empty inventory spots.  I most likely missed several items in my addicted frenzy to finish the game.

What are all the items that can be found in the game?
And where can they found?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well, I figured it out, so I decided to compile a list to help anyone else:

[image: Full inventory]

I've hidden the locations so that (if you want) you can see the list of items without ruining the reward of finding them for yourself.

---

#### THE MAP

"Map of the world"
[image: Map of the world]

> Received after clearing the rats from the basement of the last house in the village.

---

#### A TIME RING

"This item gives you a new ability in quests : you can slow down the time. If things are going too fast for you, use your time ring!"
[image: A TIME RING]

> Purchased from the Candy Merchant

---

#### THE THIRD HOUSE KEY

"This key allows you to enter the third house in the village"
[image: THE THIRD HOUSE KEY]

---

#### THE BEGINNERS' GRIMOIRE

"This grimoire provides you three spells, quite easy to cast. It is really made for beginners. You will be able to use the acid rain spell (a large quantity of acid drops will fall on your enemies), the fireball spell (a giant magic ball made of fire will fly towards your enemies), and the teleport spell (which will teleport you to an unpredictable location)."
[image: THE BEGINNERS' GRIMOIRE]

> Purchased from the sorceress.

---

#### A DESERT BIRD FEATHER

"This magic feather allows you to jump higher when you use your poto stick!"
[image: A DESERT BIRD FEATHER]

> Found by killing a bird in the "desert" quest.

---

#### POGO STICK

"This item allows you to jump in quests!"
[image: POGO STICK]

> Found by clicking on the asterisk right next to the cave on the map.

---

#### A HEART PLUG

"This heart plug, made with iron, spider legs, and a special "heart liquor" sealed in the center, will increase your health points by 20 percents!"
[image: A HEART PLUG]

> Found by following the arrows that appear on the doorways of the cave.

---

#### THE ADVANCED GRIMOIRE

"This advanced grimoire provides you two spells : the erase magic spell and the thorns shield spell. The first one will erase all the magic from a quest at some point including the spells you casted and your enemy's magic. The second will create around you a shield of floating thorns which will inflict damage upon contact."
[image: THE ADVANCED GRIMOIRE]

> Purchased from the sorceress.

---

#### A MAGICAL SPONGE

"This magical sponge allows you to squeeze yourself just like a sponge, therefore reducing your size."
[image: A MAGICAL SPONGE]

> Found on the sea floor of the "Jump into the sea" quest.

---

#### SHELL POWDER

"Shell powder is often used by farmers to improve the growth speed of their lollipops. This powder will multiply your lollipop farm production by three!"
[image: SHELL POWDER]

> Found on the sea floor of the "Jump into the sea" quest.

---

#### A MAGICAL RED SHARK FIN

"This magical fin will greatly increase the damage of your fireball spell. Finally this fireball becomes useful."
[image: A MAGICAL RED SHARK FIN]

> Found in the "Jump into the sea" quest.  Kill the sea horses, and you will start seeing sharks.  Eventually one with a red fin will appear.

---

#### THE BLACK MAGIC GRIMOIRE

"You found this grimoire in a cave, it was very hard to reach, and that was for a reason. It provides you two powerful black magic spells.  The first one will create in front of you a giant wall made of obsidian bricks, which can be useful to slow down your enemies. The second one will summon a swarm of demons attacking everyone in the quest, including you. Be careful with this one."
[image: THE BLACK MAGIC GRIMOIRE]

> Found in the hole.

---

#### A MAGICAL GREEN SHARK FIN

"This magical fin will bring the power of nature to your lollipop farm! Your production will be multiplied by 5."
[image: A MAGICAL GREEN SHARK FIN]

> Found in the "Jump into the sea" quest.  Appears after the red finned shark.

---

#### A MAGICAL PURPLE SHARK FIN

"This magical fin will provide you a new black magic spell. You can only use it once per quest. Be very careful with this one!"
[image: A MAGICAL PURPLE SHARK FIN]

> Found in the "Jump into the sea" quest.  Appears a long time after the green finned shark.

---

#### A HEART PENDANT

"This heart pendant will increase your health points as long as you keep it around your neck."
[image: A HEART PENDANT]

> Found in the hole

---

#### THE DESERT FORTRESS KEY

"This key allows you to enter the very ancient fortress located above the desert. Who knows what you could find there?"
[image: THE DESERT FORTRESS KEY]

> Found in the Hole.

---

#### A UNCORN HORN

"This magical horn belonged to a unicorn Its powerful healing powers will help you a lot. You heard that this unicorn was named Charlie."
[image: A UNCORN HORN]

> Found in the left room of Desert Fortress

---

#### A XINOPHERYDON CLAW

"This claw belonged to a xinopherydon, a two-headed ancient animal everyone believe to be extinct. It will double the damage of the weapon you're using."
[image: A XINOPHERYDON CLAW]

> Found in the left room of the Desert Fortress.  Fight the Xinopherydon on the upper level.

---

#### A PITCHFORK

"This special pitchfork allows you to loosen the soil without turning it over, therefore preserving below-ground soil ecosystems. It will triple the production of your lollipop farm."
[image: A PITCHFORK]

> Found in the Dark Room in the Castle. You click the Campfire in the middle of the room.

---

#### A TALKING CANDY

"This talking candy appeared after you put the four stones at the top of the castle's tower. He might help you to open the candy box..."
[image: A TALKING CANDY]

> Found after putting the p-l-a-y stones in the top of the tower.

---

#### THE P STONE

A bunch of gibberish
[image: THE P STONE]

> Received after completing the lighthouse challenge.

---

#### THE L STONE

A bunch of gibberish
[image: THE L STONE]

> Found in a chest at the end of the drop monster and eggs room of the castle.

---

#### THE A STONE

A bunch of gibberish
[image: THE A STONE]

> Earned by defeating the devil.

---

#### THE Y STONE

A bunch of gibberish
[image: THE Y STONE]

> Earned by defeating the developer.

Comment: I don't remember how I got several of them... If you know, I'd love to be able to make this complete!

Comment: There's also the Rocket Boots from the Desert Fortress, right room.

Comment: The P STONE is from the Lighthouse puzzle. 
The L stone is from the drop monster chest in the top room in the castle.

Comment: Thanks @PsychicSword!  @Fudgie, I wasn't really planning on adding equip-able items... but why not?  I'll start to compile a list and either add it to this answer or make another answer.  (unless someone else wants to do it?)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a collection of the equip-able inventory items:

---

#### The Octopus King crown

"When you wear this crown, you feel a lot more confident. It doesn't give any advantage in quests, but self-confidence is important!"
[image: The Octopus King crown]
Status effect: You are a lot more confident.

> Found by fighting Octopus king in cave.

---

#### The Octopus King crown with jaspers

"This enchanted crown is made with gold and red jaspers. In quests, it will frequently cast powerful magic fireballs around you. And also, it's shining!"
[image: The Octopus King crown with jaspers]
Status effect: Randomly cast powerful fireballs around you.

> Created by enchanting an Octopus King crown at the wishing well.

---

#### The Octopus King crown with obsidian

"This enchanted crown is made with gold and obsidian. It is beautiful. In quests, it will summon an Octopus King fighting on your side once in a while. What a tenacious ally!"
[image: The Octopus King crown with obsidian]
Status effect: Summon the Octopus King once in a while to help you.

> Created by enchanting an Octopus King crown at the wishing well.

---

#### The merchant hat

"This hat was sold to you by the candy merchant. The candy merchant loves candies. This hat will multiply by 7 the candies you find in quests!"
[image: The merchant hat]
Status effect: Multiplies the number of candies found in quests by 7

> Purchased from merchant.

---

#### The sorceress hat

"This hat was sold to you by the sorceress. It will enhance the effects of your spells and potions."
[image: The sorceress hat]
Status effect: Enhances your spells & potions effects

> Purchased from sorceress.

---

#### A lightweight body armor

"This body armour will offer you a weak protection. You will be slightly more resistant to your enemies attacks."
[image: A lightweight body armor]
Status effect: Damage taken reduced by 15%

> Purchased from the blacksmith.

---

#### A knight body armor

"This strong body armour will protect you. You will be more resistant to your enemies attacks."
[image: A knight body armor]
Status effect: Damage taken reduced by 30%

> Found in the "Castle's entrance" quest.

---

#### An enchanted knight body armor

"This armour is very special. You will be a LOT more resistant to your enemies attacks, but the damage of the weapon you are using will be divided by two."
[image: An enchanted knight body armor]
Status effect: Dam. taken reduced by 80%, dam. inflicted divided by 2

> Created by enchanting A knight body armor at the wishing well.

---

#### Leather gloves

"These gloves basically do nothing. But they're soft and comfortable, at least!"
[image: Leather gloves]

> Purchased from the candy merchant.

---

#### Red enchanted gloves

"These enchanted gloves emit a soft red light when it's dark around you. In quests, they will randomly cast small fireballs towards your enemies, which can definitely be useful."
[image: Red enchanted gloves]
Status effect: Randomly cast small fireballs around you.

> Created by enchanting Leather gloves at the wishing well.

---

#### Pink enchanted gloves

"These enchanted gloves leave a pink mark on everything you touch. In quests, they will heal you continuously."
[image: Pink enchanted gloves]
Status effect: Slowly regain your health points in quests.

> Created by enchanting Leather gloves at the wishing well.

---

#### Leather boots

"Simple Leather boots. Nothing special about them."
[image: Leather boots]

> Purchased from the candy merchant.

---

#### Rocket boots

"These awesome rocket boots allow you to jump in mid-air, so that you're basically flying!"
[image: Rocket boots]
Status effect: Jump in mid-air without limit.

> Found in the third room in the desert fortress (try building steps out of something you can create...)

---

#### Boots of introspection

"Take the time to breathe and calm down. If you wear these boots, you will never move as long as you touch the ground."
[image: Boots of introspection]

> Found by killing your mirrored self when you drink the X potion

---

#### Wooden sword

"A simple sword made of wood"
[image: Wooden sword]
Weapon damage: 1
Weapon speed: medium speed

> 

---

#### Iron axe

"A simple iron axe. Well sharpened. More powerful than the wooden sword."
[image: Iron axe]
Weapon damage: 3
Weapon speed: rather fast

> Purchased from the blacksmith.

---

#### Polished silver sword

"A powerful sword, recovered by spikes."
[image: Polished silver sword]
Weapon damage: 7
Weapon speed: medium speed

> Purchased from the blacksmith.

---

#### The troll's bludgeon

"You took this bludgeon from the troll guarding the bridge. It is slow but smashes your enemies quite efficiently."
[image: The troll's bludgeon]
Weapon damage: 12-16
Weapon speed: slow

> Found after killing the troll on The bridge quest

---

#### The monkey wizard staff

"This staff belonged to the naked monkey wizard you found in the cave. It will frequently cast spells by itself, targeting your enemies."
[image: The monkey wizard staff]
Weapon damage: 2
Weapon speed: very fast

> Found after killing the monkey wizard in The cave entrance quest

---

#### The monkey wizard staff (enchanted)

"This staff is faster than the non-enchanted version, and will cast a lot more spells."
[image: The monkey wizard staff (enchanted)]
Weapon damage: 2
Weapon speed: incredibly fast

> Created by enchanting The monkey wizard staff in the wishing well.

---

#### A tribal spear

"You found this tribal spear on the corpse of a tribe warrior lost in a big hole in the ground. It's a bit hard to handle at first, but once you're used to it, it's a good weapon."
[image: A tribal spear]
Weapon damage: 8
Weapon speed: fast

> Found by killing tribal warriors in The Hole quest.

---

#### A summoning tribal spear

"This magical tribal spear, in addition to being slightly more powerful than the normal tribal spear, will frequently summon tribe warriors which will help you during your quests."
[image: A summoning tribal spear]
Weapon damage: 10
Weapon speed: fast

> Created by enchanting A tribal spear in the wishing well.

---

#### A giant spoon

"This giant spoon was in a giant teapot in the desert fortress. You don't know if anyone ever used it as a spoon, but if so, it must have been someone really big. You probably don't want to meet him."
[image: A giant spoon]
Weapon damage: 70
Weapon speed: slow

> Found by defeating A teapot in the second room of The desert fortress.

---

#### A scythe

"It is said that this scythe belonged to the Death itself. It is extremely fast."
[image: A scythe]
Weapon damage: 21
Weapon speed: incredibly fast

> Purchased from the blacksmith.

---

#### The giant Spoon of Doom

"This giant spoon is even more powerful than the regular giant spoon you could find, for example in a teapot.  It's quite slow however."
[image: The giant Spoon of Doom]
Weapon damage: 315
Weapon speed: incredibly slow

> Created by enchanting A giant spoon in the wishing well.

---

Answer (score -4):

1. Map
2. Time ring
3. Third house key
4. Beginner's grimoire
5. Desert bird feather
6. Pogo stick
7. Heart plug
8. Advanced grimoire
9. Magical sponge
10. Shell Powder
11. Black magic grimoire
12. Magical red shark fin
13. Magical green shark fin
14. Magical purple shark fin
15. Heart pendant
16. Desert fortress key
17. Unicorn Horn
18. Xinopherydon claw
19. Pitchfork
20. Talking candy
21. The P stone
22. The L stone
23. The A stone
24. The Y stone

Telling you where you can find every items will take forever. Ask for the items you've missed.

Comment: The point of this website is to *help*.  If you don't want to list where to find them all, that's fine, but this is then an incomplete answer.

Comment: For the two people that upvoted this: What is wrong with you?