# what is the meaning of tower of candy box 2

Tags: candy-box-2

I don't get why there is a random tower with 4 blank spaces?
I tried pressing the spaces but nothing happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The holes are for the P, L, A and Y stones. Once you have collected all of them, put them in the holes.

Comment: how do you get the P, L, A, Y stones?

Comment: @iambobchen Check out: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/137341/58106