# Are there more resources in candy box 2?

Tags: candy-box-2

I have candies (obviously), lollipops, chocolate bars and pains au chocolat. I have finished the game.

Answer (score 8):

No that is all the resources that you can acquire in the game, aside from the items you can [collect](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/137324/full-list-of-inventory-items).

Answer (score 4):

No - that is all of the different types of available resources in Candy Box 2.