# how do you get shell powder in candy box 2

Tags: candy-box-2

how do you get shell powder in candy box 2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Full List of inventory items](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/137324/full-list-of-inventory-items)

Answer (score 0):

Referencing [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/137324/full-list-of-inventory-items) and [the wiki entry for Shell Powder](https://candybox2-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Shell_Powder), shell powder can be found in the **sea**, on the sea floor during the "Jump into the sea" quest.

[image]